# Using superpower to parse simple block oriented data structures

Tags: parsing, superpower

I could use some hints to start writing a simple parser using C# (preferably superpower or perhaps sprache) to parse files defining some simple structures like:

```
Header
  HeaderDataItem1   "Value of item 1"
  HeaderDataItem2   "Value of item 2"
End Header
(* Single line comment *)
(* Another single line comment *)
EntityInfo
  SubGroupType1
    ItemName  "Name1"
    Item1  "Value of item 1"
    Item2  "Value of item 2"
  End SubGroupType1
    :
    :
  SubGroupType1
    ItemName  "Name2"
    Item1  "Value of item 1"
    Item2  "Value of item 2"
  End SubGroupType1
End EntityInfo
```

The real case is more complex, more keywords (tokens?), deeper, contains enums etc. but not infinitely nested though.

I guess this should be very simple, but as mentioned, I would highly appreciate some start help and would possibly being able to develop further what I need.
I have checked some of the samples, but my experience in parsing is simply too little (quite experienced programming C# though)

Comment: is `Header` a constant? i.e. is it always called `Header` and is it always expected? Same with `EntityInfo`, `SubGroupType1`, etc. Also, what do the colons `:` represent? You'd need to answer those questions in order to write a complete parser for this.